# Why can't I install even if I have the required PHP version?

Tags: installation

I want to install Drupal 9.0.2 on a server with Apache2 and PHP 7.3.2.
I am getting this error.

> Your PHP installation is too old. Drupal requires at least PHP 7.3.0. See the system requirements page for more information.

The version I get with `php -v` is the following.

> PHP 7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 16:34:09) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.3.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Why does the installer says the PHP version is too old when `php -v` says it's PHP 7.3.20?

Comment: If you add a `phpinfo()` page in the site does it give you the same version as CLI?

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem with "a2dismod php7.2" .